# How can i use carbon format for this?

Tags: php, php-carbon

I have a DateTime that looks like this 20200611151423

I tried `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-d-m H:i:s', '20200611151423', 'Europe/Amsterdam');` but this gives me a "The separation symbol could not be found". Is there a way to format this in Carbon?

Comment: Remove everything but the letters. Your number has no dashes, spaces, or colons, so you don't want to put that in the format string.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem ! I tried Carbon::createFromFormat('YdmHis', '20200611151423', 'Europe/Amsterdam')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date-time value must be the same format as the value you pass as the first argument of `createFromFormat` function. Do the following:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-d-m H:i:s', '2020-06-11 15:14:23', 'Europe/Amsterdam')
```

or:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('YdmHis', '20200611151423', 'Europe/Amsterdam')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you should convert first the timestamp

```
  $dt = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(20200611151423)->toDateTimeString(); 
  Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-d-m H:i:s', $dt, 'Europe/Amsterdam');
```

or you can use this method :

```
echo Carbon::createFromTimestamp('20200611151423', 'Europe/Amsterdam')->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP');
```

Comment: That's not a timestamp, though. `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 20200611151423);` is `642101-11-19 14:23:43`. It's a date string with all non-numeric characters removed.

Comment: You can read more in this article [Carbon Docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: yep, it's not a timestamp. This is what you see when adding dashes and colons:  2020-06-11 15:14:23

Comment: For the record, this could have been a timestamp and @Neavehni, you never actually said it explicitly in the question, that's a reason enough for not using ambigous formats like this one and use as much as possible the format with - and :